# Is it Possible to apply soundex function for two strings of a Unicode Langaue (Eg: Kannada) In Sql

Tags: sql, unicode

Is it possible to check that Two Unicode language strings are equal,by using soundex sql  function .
Or Is it possible to get matching  Unicode strings from the database by passing one string in where condition of a sql query?